# Difference in meaning between What will the weather be like? and What will the weather be??

Tags: prepositions

What is the exact difference in meaning between "What will the weather be like?" and "What will the weather be?" ?

Comment: Related: [“How…?” vs. “What … like?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/220454/how-vs-what-like), and (on ELL) [“What does the weather look like” or “what is the weather like”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53769/what-does-the-weather-look-like-or-what-is-the-weather-like).

Comment: You don't need the third ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much difference between the two questions; if you were to ask a native speaker (or any speaker, really) either question, you would get the same answer.

e.g. The weather will be sunny.

For some reason, we generally have a term after 'What will the weather be?', so 'What will the weather be like?' sounds more correct, though 'What will the weather be tomorrow?' is also fine.

I suppose we add the term 'like' simply because we cannot guarantee what the specifically will be exactly. Note that we do not answer the question with 'like'.

e.g. What will the weather be like?

The weather will be cloudy. (*But we don't know how cloudy, whether it will rain or not, etc.)*

Comment: I wonder whether this phraseology varies across different English-speaking regions?

Comment: I don't think it does vary, consider this similar post: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/220454/how-vs-what-like
and another somewhat similar post about weather terms:
http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53769/what-does-the-weather-look-like-or-what-is-the-weather-like

Comment: Thanks.  I've duplicated your links in a comment directly underneath the Q., where they will be more prominent.